# Read from file system via FileSystem object

Tags: java, jar, path, directory, filesystems

In order to list file contents of a specific directory on classpath I'm using the new `FileSystem` and `Path` features of Java 7. In one deployment the directory is stored on file system, directly. In another deployment it is stored into a JAR file.

My approach works fine with JAR files: I create a `FileSystem` object which refers to the JAR file and access the content via `Path` object.

```
        ...
        URI dir = ...
        String[] array = dir.toString().split("!");

        try (final FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create(array[0]), new HashMap<String, Object>()))
        {
            final Path directory = fs.getPath(array[1]);
            try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(directory))
            {
        ...
```

Due to the dir object has following value, it works:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/pax/.../Detector-1.0.jar!/org/.../destinationdir
```

But in the other environment the destination directory is stored on file system, directly. dir object contains the value:

```
file:/C:/Users/pax/.../destinationdir
```

`FileSystems.newFileSystem(...)` always throws following exception for `/` and `file:/C:/Users/pax/.../destinationdir` as URI:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path component should be '/'
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.checkUri(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:68)
```

How do you use `FileSystem.newFileSystem` for destinations on file system?

Is there a better approach in order to list the directories content independently from its specific kind of storage (file system or JAR file)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following question's resolution tackles the issue ("destination on file system" versus "destination in JAR file") by try-catch approach: [NIO2: how to generically map a URI to a Path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195890/nio2-how-to-generically-map-a-uri-to-a-path)

This utility method tries to obtain a correct `Path` instance. But there may occur a further problem: If this destination resource is contained by a JAR file (instead of file system) then you can only access the resource via its associated `FileSystem` instance which must not be closed! So, your helper method needs to return the `Path` object as well as the `FileSystem` instance (only required if it's not on file system directly). The invoker has to close the `FileSystem` object, manually:

```
public static PathReference getPath(final URI resPath) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        // first try getting a path via existing file systems
        return new PathReference(Paths.get(resPath), null);
    }
    catch (final FileSystemNotFoundException e)
    {
        /*
         * not directly on file system, so then it's somewhere else (e.g.:
         * JAR)
         */
        final Map<String, ?> env = Collections.emptyMap();
        final FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(resPath, env);
        return new PathReference(fs.provider().getPath(resPath), fs);
    }
}
```

The wrapper class `PathReference` should implement `AutoClosable` so that it can be used in `try` block:

```
public class PathReference implements AutoCloseable
{
   ...
    @Override
   public void close() throws Exception
    {
        if (this.fileSystem != null)
            this.fileSystem.close();
    }

    public Path getPath()
    {
        return this.path;
    }

    public FileSystem getFileSystem()
    {
        return this.fileSystem;
    }
}
```

This makes the release of the `FileSystem` instance a bit more transparent:

```
...
try (final PathReference fileObj = SignatureUtils.getPath(file))
{
    ...
    try (InputStream fileStream = Files.newInputStream(fileObj.getPath()))
    {
    ...
```